# compressing data with HDFStore

Tags: python, r, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I am newbie to pytables and had a question regarding storing compressed pandas DataFrame. My current code is:

```
import pandas
# HDF5 file name
H5name="C:\\MyDir\\MyHDF.h5"

# create HDF5 file
store=pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore(H5name)

# write a pandas DataFrame to the HDF5 file created
myDF.to_hdf(H5name,"myDFname",append=True)

# read the pandas DataFrame back from the HDF5 file created
myDF1=pandas.io.pytables.read_hdf(H5name,"myDFname")

# close the file
store.close()
```

When I checked the size of the HDF5 created, the size (212kb) was much larger than the original csv file (58kb) I used to create the pandas DataFrame.

So, I tried out compression by (deleting the HDF5 file) and recreating

```
# create HDF5 file
store=pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore(H5name,complevel=1)
```

and the size of the file created did not change. I tried all `complevels` from 1 to 9 and the size still remained the same.

I tried to add

```
# create HDF5 file
store=pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore(H5name,complevel=1,complib="zlib")
```

but it had no change in compression.

What could be the problem?

Also, ideally I would like to use a compression similar to what R does for its save function  (e.g. in my case the 58kb file was saved to a size of 27kb in RData)? Do I need to do any additional serialization in Python to reduce the size?

**EDIT:**

I am using Python 3.3.3 and Pandas 0.13.1

**EDIT:**
I tried with a larger file 487MB csv file, whose RData `size` (via R's save function) is 169MB. For larger files, I do see the compressions. Bzip2 gave the best compression of 202MB (level=9) and was the slowest to read/write. Blosc compression (level=9) gave the largest size of 276MB, but was much faster to write/read.

Not sure what R does differently in its `save` function, but it's both equally fast and much more compressed than any of these compression algos.

Comment: you need to specify a ``complib`` as well. see docs here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#compression

Comment: Copy and paste problem? You are not passing `store` to the `to_hdf` function. Therefore any parameters passed to the HDFStore constructor don’t have an effect. Easiest is to pass the complib and complevel parameters to `to_hdf` and to not create the HDFStore object explicitly at all.

Answer (score 2):

You have a really tiny file here. HDF5 basically chunks your data; usually 64KB is a minimum chunk size. Depedening on what the data is, it might not even compress at that size.

You can try `msgpack` for a simple soln for this size data. HDF5 is quite efficient for larger sizes and will compress quite nicely.